# How to use Samsung Galaxy S2 front camera?

Tags: android, opencv

Anybody knows how to use front camera in Samsung Galaxy S2 android program? The best way would be to do it using opencv video capture facility Videocapture but if it is not possible native camera would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    // High Quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    // start the Video Capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    ...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Video file URI in data.getData();
       }
   }
}
```

This would allow the user to choose camera in the default camera application.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) for more info.